# Error:(172, 25) error: BatteryManager() is not public in BatteryManager; cannot be accessed from outside package android

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-os-handler

I am using below code and its working properly with `compileSdkVersion 22`

```
int capacityValue=new BatteryManager().getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
```

but when trying to change `compileSdkVersion 23` then its displaying compile time error

> Error:(172, 25) error: BatteryManager() is not public in BatteryManager; cannot be accessed from outside package android

plz help me.

Comment: `is not public in BatteryManager`

Answer (score 0):

You have to register a reciever and get the info from the received intent.

Some sample code here: http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-sdk-get-device-battery-information/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have registered broadcast and am able to get every property. but **BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY** this property is added above to 21 api .and i am using below code `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
      int capacityValue=new BatteryManager().getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
      capacity.setText(String.valueOf(capacityValue));
      batteryInformation.setCapacity(String.valueOf(capacityValue));
     }else{
      findViewById(R.id.capacity_layout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }`

Comment: Np mate. Accept the answer for others to know it's working.